# Default deploy-mode with spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am launching a spark job with `--master yarn` using spark 2.4.3.

What is the default value `deploy-mode` is set to? Is it `client` or `cluster` ?

Comment: Client. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit

Comment: Ooops, missed it in the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @blackbishop, [default value](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit) for `deploy-mode` is `client`.